# Axios get request always returns a blank response

Tags: axios

I launched my app on heroku.
And ever since all of my axios get request return a blank html.

```
    axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_baseServerurl + '/create/get-users')
    axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_baseServerurl + '/create/get-users')
```

the response i get is always blank.

[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRVk0.png)

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSgte.png)

but if i change the same request to a post it works fine.

The get request works fine when i try it on my localhost. But when i deploy it on heroku it returns blank.

```
router.post('/get-users', (req,res) => {
    res.json("asdsadas")
})

router.route('/get-users').get((req,res) => {
    res.json("yes")
})
```

the POST request works but GET request returns a 304.

Comment: I know you have no time, but can you clarify that question too much? provide what you're doing on the back end, and what exactly are you doing with Axios on the front end. your question does not have a real answer, that's not a question. either you ask a proper question or you'll get no proper answer

Answer (score 0):

The 304 HTTP Status code means that the resource has not been modified since the last get request. This indicates that the server thinks you already have a copy of up-to-date data. The Server makes this assumption by looking at the If-None-Match and If-Modified-Since in your request header. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_redirection)

These are the actions you could take:

1. Cache the data manually on your first successful request (if there is one, otherwise there must be an error in the usage of the If-None-Match and If-Modified-Since headers) and re-use the cached data if the server returns a 304 status code.
2. Disable the mechanism and live with the fact that you might request the same data the server already gave you.